# How do you show that a function implements an interface?

Tags: typescript

With TypeScript, you can show a variable implements an interface with:

```js
type Component<P = { children: string | number }> = (
  props: P
) => string | number;

const Children1: Component = props => props.children;
```

which results in:

```
const Children1 = props => props.children;
```

Is it possible to achieve a similar thing with a regular function? The output of which would be something like:

```
// Where does the type information go?
function Children2(props) {
    return props.children;
}
```

You can play with this example on the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWzHAdhFwA8AFKBeKAbygGMALASwBsATAJ3QC4oBnYOilAcygB8oUAVwQAjCHSgBfAHz4oACgBQUKGDpwwLZtkUBKfLLYdufAcLF0A3IsUlUbWJVoMUARmbwkqdMDlqNLAaq6poAdOTU9OjWigBmgigkwBSojpEuAEzy-pr6hMpQDMCCdCjBAeFOUSjWkopAA)

(As to why, regular functions are useful because you can hoist them)

Comment: Just use `const name: type = function () {}`

Comment: in your first example, the transpiled output would be the same whether you typed it or not. typing the function isn't for the transpiler, it's for the developer so your intellisense is better

Comment: @jonrsharpe in your example the output is the same as the first example which means you can't use it in a hoisted way, e.g. declare functions at the bottom of the file and use them at the top.

Comment: but WHY is typing the parameter type and return type not enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't annotate a function the way you want to.  There is a [suggestion in GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16918) to support this, marked as "needs investigation".  If you want to see this happen you might want to go to that issue and give it a  and/or describe your use case if it's more compelling than what's already there.

The closest I can get to your intent is to use conditional types like the predefined [`ReturnType<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypet) and the related `Parameters<T>` type:

```
function Children2(...[props]: Parameters<Component>): ReturnType<Component> {
    return props.children;
}
```

That should behave similarly, and it shouldn't scale too horribly.  It is likely to behave incorrectly with generic functions, unfortunately.  I'd stick with using a `const` variable if you need this functionality and work around the hoisting issue.

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWzHAdhFwA8AFKBeKAbygGMALASwBsATAJ3QC4oBnYOilAcygB8oUAVwQAjCHSgBfAHz4oACgBQUKGDpwwLZtkUBKfLLYdufAcLF0A3IsUlUbWJVoMUARmbwkqdMDlqNLAaq6poAdOTU9OjWigBmgigkwBSojpEuAEzyoTkA2v6aALraAIZ0JQgQwOIsmJ7IaBjSuswASlWCdCgAKuAQdYgNPrKEyipQDMCdKMEB4U5RKNaSQA)

Comment: Shame! Thanks for the link to the Github issue and a roughly equivalent suggestion. :)

Answer (score 1):

typing a function is like this:

```
function myFunction(a: ParamType): ReturnType { 
  // your function here
}
```

then the interface of the function is inferred from the parameter and return types.

the return type of your function can often be inferred by the typescript interpreter. Function types are most useful if you're declaring an interface that other classes need to implement.

Comment: Doesn't that show that `myFunction` returns something of type `MyFunctionType` as opposed to being `MyFunctionType`?

Comment: yes, sorry, early morning, the interface of the function is just inferred from the return type and the parameter types. If you need it to be more explicit than that, then you need to use a variable.. maybe a more concrete case of why you need explicit typing vs inferred on functions would be helpful

Comment: This is perfectly valid and works for the simple cases, however, when the type information comes from a library it can be cumbersome to import all the individual parameter types and return types.

Comment: in those cases, you're probably better off just declaring them as constants in a separate file and just importing the functions, so hoisting isn't really a concern